# Stream post URL security option

Tags: facebook, api

I get this error

> (#100) The post's links must direct to the application's connect or
>   canvas URL

when I try to publish image to my wall.
I found that I should disable "Stream post URL security" to avoid this message BUT this option is already disabled.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding 'action links' as attachments to the stream post, those must always link to your canvas or connect URL regardless of that security setting - at least, it was announced that this would be the case from  April 1st 2012 onwards; maybe it's happening early for some reason?

Comment: Thanks a lot for very fast reply. i will check.